# Multiple gemfire cache-server on same host machine

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Hi i want to start more than one gemfire cache-server on same host using Spring gemfire 8.1.Please find below gemfire configuration file. I want to start GFServer1 and GFServer2 on same host i.e.HOSTNAME using Spring Gemfire configuration. I want to avoid gfsh command and start everything from eclipse and connect client to these servers on the same host.
Thanks in advance

```
    <util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
        <prop key="name">Locator_Dev</prop>
        <prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
        <prop key="locators">HOSTNAME[1099]</prop>
        <prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
        <prop key="http-service-port">8181</prop>
        <prop key="jmx-manager">true</prop>
        <prop key="jmx-manager-port">1199</prop>
        <prop key="jmx-manager-start">true</prop>
        <prop key="start-locator">HOSTNAME[1099]</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties" />


    <gfe:cache-server id="GFServer1" auto-startup="true"
        bind-address="HOSTNAME" port="40411" host-name-for-clients="HOSTNAME"
        load-poll-interval="2000" max-connections="22" max-threads="16"
        max-message-count="1000" max-time-between-pings="30000" >

        <gfe:subscription-config eviction-type="ENTRY"
            capacity="1000" disk-store="diskStore1" />
    </gfe:cache-server>


    <gfe:cache-server id="GFServer2" auto-startup="true"
        bind-address="HOSTNAME" port="40412" host-name-for-clients="HOSTNAME"
        load-poll-interval="2000" max-connections="22" max-threads="16"
        max-message-count="1000" max-time-between-pings="30000" >

        <gfe:subscription-config eviction-type="ENTRY"
            capacity="1000" disk-store="diskStore1" />
    </gfe:cache-server>


   <gfe:disk-store id="diskStore1" queue-size="50"
        auto-compact="true" max-oplog-size="10" time-interval="9999">
        <gfe:disk-dir
            location="D:\NP\WorkSpace\GemfireRegionSolutionNStart\disk-store\store_1"
            max-size="20" />
        <gfe:disk-dir
            location="D:\NP\WorkSpace\GemfireRegionSolutionNStart\disk-store\store_2"
            max-size="20" />
    </gfe:disk-store>


    <gfe:replicated-region id="customer" name="Customer">
    </gfe:replicated-region>

    <gfe:replicated-region id="bookMaster" name="BookMaster">
    </gfe:replicated-region>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... so you have a few options from within your IDE (e.g. Eclipse).

If you break the Spring config above into 2 separate Spring (Data GemFire) XML configuration files, each containing 1 of the `<gfe:cache-server>` elements, call these files, for example, spring-gemfire-server1-context.xml and spring-gemfire-server2-context.xml, you could run the Spring-based/configure GemFire "data nodes" and Cache Servers with the following...

[SimpleSpringApplication](https://github.com/jxblum/scalable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/spring-gemfire-bootstrap/src/main/java/sample/java/app/SimpleSpringApplication.java)

Where the argument to the simple little Java "main" program is the file system path to 1 of the Spring XML configuration files noted above.

Better yet, you can launch these Spring (GemFire) configs with a SpringBoot application using something like...

[UsefulSpringBootGemFireApplication](https://github.com/jxblum/scalable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/spring-gemfire-bootstrap/src/main/java/sample/spring/boot/app/UsefulSpringBootGemFireApplication.java)

As you can see here, you can use either the `@Import` annotation if you are configuring GemFire from Spring using Java-based Configuration (for example, [UsefulSpringBasedGemFireConfiguration](https://github.com/jxblum/scalable-spring-gemfire/blob/master/spring-gemfire-configuration/src/main/java/sample/java/config/UsefulSpringBasedGemFireConfiguration.java)), or in your case, with XML using the 
`@ImportResoruce("/classpath/to/spring-gemfire-server1-context.xml")` annotation.

It maybe possible (not sure) to pass a System property value into the @ImportResource annotation, like so...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("${spring-gemfire-context-xml-location}")
class SpringBootGemFireApplication {
  ...
}
```

Then, from within your IDE, you can create 2 separate "run profiles" using the same `SpringBootGemFireApplication` class and then setting the System property (e.g. `-Dspring-gemfire-context-xml-location=/path/to/spring-gemfire-server1-context.xml`) appropriately for each configuration.

Remember, you can use Spring's [ResourceLoader path qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-resourceloader) (e.g. file:, http:, etc) to resolve your Spring GemFire config from different source locations (CLASSPATH, file system, etc)... see the table ("Table 7.1 Resource strings") in hyperlinked section of the *Spring Framework Reference Guide*.

In the worst case, you need to create 2 separate, but nearly identical SpringBoot application Java main classes to launch your 2 configuration files for each GemFire Data Node (& CacheServer) JVM process.  However, hopefully using the System property approach allows you to recycle the same class in 2 separate run profiles.

So, this leaves you with 2 GemFire Data Node JVM processes now.  But, what about he Locator?

Well, you can continue to embed the Locator in the GemFire Data Node Server JVM process as before, but if you really want a standalone Locator JVM process, then you can use the following, "experimental" class...

[LocatorLauncherFactoryBean](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/config/LocatorLauncherFactoryBean.java)

This class uses GemFire's [LocatorLauncher](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/distributed/LocatorLauncher.html) class to configure and bootstrap a *GemFire Locator* from Spring config.  I created this class over 2 years ago for a customer POC as example of how a developer might configure a *GemFire Locator* from Spring config.

The Spring XML configuration (used by the `SpringBootGemFireApplication` `@ImportResoruce` annotation, in yet another "run profile" and System property combination), would look similar to the following...

[locator.xml](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/resources/locator.xml)

Now, you have effectively achieved 3 separate GemFire JVM processes (2 Servers and 1 Locator).  You can scale this from with our IDE to however many Servers and Locators you want, and Pulse will show all of these in the cluster, providing the cluster is configured correctly (Servers pointed at Locators, etc).

Hope this helps.

Cheers!
John

Comment: Hi John with above instruction i am able to start individual java instance for locator, GFserver1 and GFserver2 from eclipse using spring boot the only change i have added is "-Dserver.port=8002" to fix jetty port bind issue.Now i have 3 instance of members up and running

Comment: But I am not able launch pulse and don't know how my locator will discover the servers (GFserver1, GfServer2) because I don't see any configuration where my server/locator are linked with each other.I am also not able to see locator folder in workspace when i start locator instance with previous configuration(Single context file) i was able to generate locator folder in my workplace. Sorry for my limited knowledge in gemire.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you have posted will create two cache-servers within the same JVM, i.e it will open up two ports within the same process.

If this is not what you want, i.e you want two distinct process, in eclipse you will have to provide two runtime configurations to start the two servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Swapnil, but with the above configuration I am able to see server count as 1 on Pulse web console and able to see the only locator name on the pulse. Whereas if I start servers from GFSH I am able to see all 3 members, i.e. locator, GFserver1 and GFServer2 on the pulse. May be 2 distinct processes for each server can solve my problem, can you please suggest how to approach with that.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific question?  As @Swapnil points out, this will start 2 GemFire "Cache Servers" (ServerSockets listening for Cache Clients) as you have appropriately configured on the same host within the same JVM.  This will work regardless of how this is executed (i.e. IDE, command-line, from Gfsh or from Spring Boot).

Let us know if you have a more specific question, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, if the configuration looks appropriate when I load this context file from eclipse I am able to see server count as 1 on Pulse web console with no server member name and able to see the only locator name on the pulse. But this is not the case when I start locator, GFServer1 and GFServer2 from GFSH, when started from GFSH I am able to see all 3 members on pulse with proper diagrammatic representation.Pulse should display all 3 members when started from eclipse.

Comment: You are confusing the following... 1. gfsh>start locator --name=A 2. gfsh>start server --name=X 3. gfsh>start server --name=Y with the above configuration.  They are not the same.  'start locator' starts a separate GemFire JVM process running a Locator.  'start server' starts a GemFire cache data node (not necessarily a "Cache Server", which is just a ServerSocket listening for Cache Clients as in the Spring cfg above).  So, what you have is 1 GemFire data node with 2 ServerSockets listening for cache client connections and an "embedded" Locator all in a single GemFire JVM process.

Comment: I am sorry for that John, but if want to start multiple gemfire server instances from eclipse how should i proceed and able to see appropriate server names, locator  on pulse Or in a simpler way how can i achieve  "gfsh>start locator --name=A 2. gfsh>start server --name=B 3. gfsh>start server --name=C" using Spring Gemfire with eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation John, I will start individual java instances for each of these members with Spring Gemfire+eclipse

Answer (score 1):

So you can configure the [LocatorLauncherFactoryBean](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/config/LocatorLauncherFactoryBean.java), for example, like so...

```
<uti:properties id="gemfireProperties">
  <prop key="log-level">config</prop>
  <prop key="http-service-port">8181</prop>
  <prop key="jmx-manager">true</prop>
  <prop key="jmx-manager-port">1199</prop>
  <prop key="jmx-manager-start">true</prop>
  <prop key="locators">host1[10334],host2[11235],...,hostN[20668]</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="locator" class="org.spring.data.gemfire.config.LocatorLauncherFactoryBean">
  <property name="gemfireProperties" ref="gemfireProperties"/>
  <property name="memberName" value="SpringDataGemFireLocator"/>
  <property name="bindAddress" value="10.124.12.24"/>
  <property name="port" value="12480"/>
</bean>
```

As you may have noticed, this Locator can join other Locators in the GemFire Cluster, which were specified in the "`gemfireProperties`" bean with the "`locators`" GemFire System property.

NOTE: the "`bindAddress`" property to the `LocatorLauncherFactoryBean` is only necessary if the localhost where this Locator will be running has multiple NICs and you want to bind to a specific NIC.

Also, I have set the JMX Manager GemFire System properties to enable the Locator  to become and actually start a Manager (on port 1199).  This allows you to connect to this Locator from Gfsh either with `gfsh>connect --locator=localhost[12480]` or with `gfsh>connect --jmx-manager=localhost[1199]`.

Basically, the "`gemfireProperties`" bean allows you to configure any [valid GemFire System property](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/reference/topics/gemfire_properties.html).

Now, since this Locator is running from within your IDE, you will need to configure the "run profile" with a `$GEMFIRE` environment variable pointing at a [GemFire distribution downloaded from Pivotal's website](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gemfire) in order to get Pulse running from this Locator.  This is [expected by the GemFire Manager's ManagementAgent](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/develop/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/management/internal/ManagementAgent.java#L158-L288) when making a decision of whether to 1. start the embedded HTTP Service (Jetty) running GemFire's out-of-box webapps (e.g. Pulse) and 2. whether it can find Pulse and start the webapp.  The ManagementAgent [looks for Pulse](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/develop/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/management/internal/ManagementAgent.java#L190-L198) in the distro.

For instance, I set my $GEMFIRE environment variable to...

/Users/jblum/Downloads/Pivotal/GemStone/Products/GemFire/Pivotal_GemFire_820_b17919_Linux

Now, to get your individiual Spring-configured GemFire Servers to connect to the cluster, that is simple.

Again, you only need a "`gemfireProperties`" bean defined in each Spring GemFire Server XML configuration file with the "locators" GemFire System property defined, e.g. ...

```
<uti:properties id="gemfireProperties">
  <prop key="log-level">config</prop>
  <prop key="locators">localhost[12480]</prop>
</util:properties>

<gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties"/>
```

This configuration will enable the GemFire Data Nodes to connect to the cluster, and this cluster will be visible from Pulse, if everything is setup correctly.

Again, hope this helps.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Hi John thank you very much for the detailed steps above, I tried all the steps provided above but unable to start locator from eclispe this was confirmed by gfsh fail connect.This is my locator.xml

Comment: <util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
   <prop key="log-level">config</prop>
   <prop key="http-service-port">8181</prop>
   <prop key="jmx-manager">true</prop>
   <prop key="jmx-manager-port">1199</prop>
   <prop key="jmx-manager-start">true</prop>
   <prop key="locators">HOSTNAME[12480]</prop>
   <prop key="start-locator">HOSTNAMEm[12480]</prop>   
  </util:properties>
 <bean id="locator"

Comment: class="com.gemfire.locator.launcher.LocatorLauncherFactoryBean">
  <property name="gemfireProperties" ref="gemfireProperties" />
  <property name="memberName" value="SpringDataGemFireLocator" />
  <property name="bindAddress" value="HOSTNAME" />
  <property name="port" value="12480" />
 </bean>

Comment: Hi John, I am now able to start all 3 members [locator, GFServer1, GFserver2] from eclipse using Spring Data gemfire as individual Java process and same appropriately displayed on the pulse. The only change I did is I have used spring not Spring Boot and a crucial change is incorporating  dummy cache-server entry in locator.xml without that locator was not able to start as an individual process. The Locator is configured in GFserver1 and GFServer2 individual context file as mentioned by you above.Thank a ton for your help :)

Comment: Hi, just an update as I  mentioned above  a crucial change made by me in locator.xml is adding a dummy cache-server, actually we don't need this dummy entry of cache-server only regions entry in locator.xml is enough to start locator as an individual process.